# Cyipopt fails to converge for NLP problem which fmincon() can solve

Tags: python, matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, ipopt

I'm currently trying to implement a python script for solving a constrained nonlinear optimization problem with ~800 variables and 2 constraints, one linear and one nonlinear. There already exists a Matlab implementation of this script and I'm trying to use `cyipopt` to implement an equivalent Python implementation that produces similar results.

The Matlab code has analytic solutions for both the objective and constraint and jacobian, which I've rewritten entirely in Python, and uses L-BFGS for hessian approximation. Calling the Python jacobian functions from fmincon() results in the same solution so I think these functions are correct, and I've also used the derivative checkers in both `fmincon()` and `cyipopt` to make sure. However, my Python implementation doesn't converge and fails to match the performance of the Matlab code. In particular, the objective doesn't decrease smoothly. Here's some example output from Ipopt:

```
This is Ipopt version 3.14.4, running with linear solver MUMPS 5.2.1.

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:     1602
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        0
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:        0

Total number of variables............................:      801
                     variables with only lower bounds:        0
                variables with lower and upper bounds:      267
                     variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:        2
Total number of inequality constraints...............:        0
        inequality constraints with only lower bounds:        0
   inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
        inequality constraints with only upper bounds:        0

iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0  1.6958872e-01 5.68e-14 1.04e-02   0.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 0.00e+00   0
   1  2.1548097e-01 3.25e+00 7.09e+00   0.6 3.87e+00    -  9.90e-01 4.34e-01f  1
   2  1.7668628e-01 3.05e+00 8.15e+00   0.9 2.38e+00    -  1.00e+00 9.72e-01f  1
   3  1.7381539e-01 1.78e-01 3.39e+00   0.2 1.09e+00    -  7.37e-01 1.00e+00h  1
   4  1.7270930e-01 4.47e-03 2.42e-01  -0.5 2.10e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   5  1.7178940e-01 4.69e-03 4.70e-02  -1.2 7.62e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
   6  1.7055753e-01 5.01e-03 8.89e-03  -1.9 1.21e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   7  1.6692096e-01 1.04e-02 1.15e-03  -2.9 7.68e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   8  1.6323948e-01 3.18e-01 8.33e-03  -3.3 5.42e-01    -  9.42e-01 1.00e+00h  1
   9  1.6005166e-01 1.43e-01 6.64e-03  -9.3 2.50e-01    -  5.61e-01 1.00e+00h  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  10  1.5786474e-01 1.22e-01 4.18e-03  -3.7 4.04e-01    -  7.71e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  11  1.5672747e-01 6.04e-02 5.11e-03  -4.2 1.61e-01    -  9.61e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  12  1.5472463e-01 2.40e-02 2.34e-03  -4.8 1.23e-01    -  9.96e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  13  1.5533721e-01 9.66e-04 6.81e-03  -5.0 1.84e-01    -  9.99e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  14  1.5377085e-01 3.02e-02 3.08e-03  -5.3 1.65e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  15  1.5361137e-01 2.09e-02 4.51e-03  -5.7 1.11e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  16  1.5296208e-01 6.95e-03 1.95e-03  -6.0 8.23e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  17  1.5273048e-01 1.90e-03 1.01e-03  -7.0 3.83e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  18  1.5311695e-01 4.91e-05 5.20e-03  -8.0 2.13e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  19  1.5262106e-01 7.92e-03 6.41e-03  -5.9 4.57e-01    -  1.00e+00 2.30e-01h  2
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  20  1.5261389e-01 1.19e-02 1.27e-02  -3.9 4.90e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.02e-01h  2
  21  1.5310130e-01 4.88e-02 4.09e-03  -3.6 2.90e-01    -  4.10e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  22  1.5330300e-01 2.75e-02 3.72e-03  -3.9 1.29e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  23  1.5201654e-01 1.23e-02 1.40e-03  -3.9 9.69e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  24  1.5227903e-01 3.92e-04 6.45e-03  -4.8 2.11e-01    -  9.86e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  25  1.5495353e-01 1.86e-04 1.26e-02  -4.5 3.70e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  26  1.5557422e-01 3.93e-05 4.07e-03  -4.6 3.53e-01    -  1.18e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  27  1.5281467e-01 7.97e-02 4.35e-03  -4.3 3.09e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  28  1.6236141e-01 3.83e-02 1.24e-02  -4.4 4.15e-01    -  7.25e-01 8.80e-01H  1
  29  1.5299068e-01 8.52e-04 6.17e-03  -4.4 2.48e-01    -  7.17e-02 1.00e+00F  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  30  1.5139425e-01 2.53e-02 3.94e-03  -4.4 9.96e-01    -  2.38e-01 1.55e-01h  3
  31  1.5138493e-01 5.50e-04 3.76e-03  -4.8 2.40e-01    -  9.94e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  32  1.5200809e-01 2.14e-04 5.16e-03  -4.9 1.32e-01    -  9.96e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  33  1.5074554e-01 1.86e-02 1.91e-03  -5.0 1.77e-01    -  9.98e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  34  1.5130813e-01 1.49e-04 3.53e-03  -5.6 1.56e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  35  1.5036412e-01 1.28e-02 1.63e-03  -5.7 1.18e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  36  1.5026330e-01 6.65e-04 8.92e-04  -7.2 3.49e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  37  1.5076495e-01 1.34e-04 5.36e-03  -7.7 1.20e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  38  1.5066012e-01 1.69e-02 6.61e-03  -7.9 1.11e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  39  1.5005302e-01 1.25e-02 1.81e-03  -8.0 1.05e-01    -  5.44e-01 1.00e+00h  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  40  1.5001109e-01 3.87e-03 2.08e-03  -8.6 4.98e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  41  1.4987818e-01 2.98e-03 2.39e-03  -9.7 5.14e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  42  1.5014976e-01 2.70e-05 3.82e-03  -9.8 1.02e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  43  1.4997585e-01 1.01e-02 5.16e-03 -10.4 6.66e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  44  1.4970903e-01 9.51e-03 2.36e-03 -10.5 8.90e-02    -  8.37e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  45  1.4940598e-01 2.37e-03 9.31e-04 -11.0 4.20e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  46  1.4968497e-01 2.68e-05 4.63e-03 -11.0 1.21e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  47  1.4995823e-01 1.29e-06 7.01e-03 -11.0 3.32e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  48  1.4974993e-01 1.46e-02 6.86e-03  -9.0 2.03e+00    -  1.00e+00 1.18e-01f  2
  49  1.4948599e-01 1.72e-02 5.95e-03  -9.1 7.57e-01    -  2.53e-01 8.53e-02h  3
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  50  1.5186145e-01 6.77e-04 8.93e-03  -9.1 2.87e-01    -  7.46e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  51  1.5120058e-01 1.35e-03 4.47e-03  -9.1 3.78e-01    -  1.19e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  52  1.5550082e-01 1.54e-04 8.87e-03  -9.1 3.78e-01    -  5.42e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  53  1.5020757e-01 1.12e-04 4.29e-03  -9.1 4.29e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  54  1.4918169e-01 1.28e-02 1.97e-03  -9.1 1.68e+00    -  2.17e-01 6.23e-02h  3
  55  1.5133875e-01 4.49e-05 8.71e-03  -9.5 2.28e-01    -  9.87e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  56  1.4882545e-01 2.34e-02 2.51e-03  -9.6 1.72e-01    -  4.77e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  57  1.4946850e-01 1.48e-02 6.52e-03 -10.4 1.07e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  58  1.4859822e-01 5.15e-03 2.33e-03 -10.5 6.48e-02    -  9.27e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  59  1.4902635e-01 7.60e-05 4.53e-03 -11.0 1.06e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  60  1.4843429e-01 4.65e-03 1.51e-03 -11.0 7.41e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  61  1.4839694e-01 1.37e-03 2.49e-03 -11.0 3.13e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  62  1.4830507e-01 3.51e-04 8.59e-04 -11.0 2.56e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  63  1.4849382e-01 1.36e-05 5.56e-03 -11.0 1.22e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  64  1.4823266e-01 3.86e-03 1.66e-03 -11.0 9.19e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  65  1.4821480e-01 5.60e-04 1.20e-03 -11.0 1.53e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  66  1.4818681e-01 1.50e-04 2.13e-04 -11.0 1.25e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  67  1.4816045e-01 1.46e-04 5.02e-04 -11.0 1.61e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  68  1.4850582e-01 5.85e-05 5.29e-03 -11.0 1.57e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  69  1.5001793e-01 1.58e-06 1.08e-02 -11.0 1.41e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  70  1.4861627e-01 2.68e-07 5.43e-03 -11.0 2.13e-01    -  2.10e-01 1.00e+00F  1
  71  1.4842174e-01 1.21e-02 4.02e-03 -10.6 3.61e-01    -  1.00e+00 2.50e-01f  3
  72  1.4816338e-01 4.71e-03 2.55e-03 -10.7 6.93e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  73  1.4841277e-01 1.20e-04 5.26e-03 -10.7 1.25e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  74  1.4923205e-01 4.65e-05 7.02e-03 -11.0 9.58e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  75  1.4793006e-01 1.50e-02 1.22e-03 -11.0 1.02e-01    -  9.33e-01 1.00e+00h  1
  76  1.4790107e-01 1.98e-03 2.30e-03 -11.0 4.36e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  77  1.4795403e-01 6.21e-06 2.74e-03 -11.0 3.90e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  78  1.4783354e-01 3.00e-03 1.85e-03 -11.0 5.85e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  79  1.4775646e-01 1.00e-03 1.66e-03 -11.0 2.36e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  80  1.4772077e-01 2.46e-04 8.16e-04 -11.0 1.37e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  81  1.4772337e-01 1.36e-06 1.67e-03 -11.0 2.97e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  82  1.4800983e-01 3.43e-07 4.69e-03 -11.0 1.73e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  83  1.4785970e-01 3.85e-03 5.48e-03 -10.2 1.53e+00    -  1.00e+00 7.61e-02f  3
  84  1.4778198e-01 6.41e-03 6.58e-03 -10.3 3.42e+00    -  6.76e-02 2.92e-02h  3
  85  1.4773098e-01 1.02e-02 5.56e-03 -10.3 2.22e+00    -  6.49e-02 4.72e-02h  3
  86  1.5775339e-01 1.78e-04 7.17e-03 -10.3 1.27e+00    -  1.35e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  87  1.5716495e-01 1.63e-03 5.41e-03 -10.3 1.70e+00    -  1.70e-01 3.17e-02h  4
  88  1.5247575e-01 1.33e-04 4.44e-03 -10.3 3.35e-01    -  5.46e-01 1.00e+00H  1
  89  1.5188072e-01 1.15e-03 3.96e-03 -10.3 1.80e+00    -  7.48e-01 3.87e-02h  5
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  90  1.5109270e-01 2.99e-03 3.54e-03 -10.3 1.65e+00    -  4.22e-01 5.10e-02h  4
  91  1.4947946e-01 5.89e-02 4.20e-03 -10.3 1.50e+01    -  4.46e-02 2.31e-02h  2
  92  1.4898332e-01 5.71e-02 3.70e-03 -10.3 6.05e-01    -  3.30e-01 1.30e-01h  3
  93  1.4893398e-01 4.01e-02 6.60e-03 -10.3 1.73e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  94  1.4813809e-01 2.83e-02 2.88e-03 -10.3 2.64e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  95  1.4953181e-01 5.14e-04 7.13e-03 -10.3 1.61e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
  96  1.4757049e-01 2.19e-02 1.86e-03 -10.3 1.12e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  97  1.4838902e-01 1.46e-02 5.65e-03 -10.8 1.05e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  98  1.4742559e-01 8.28e-03 5.50e-04 -10.9 7.16e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
  99  1.4739592e-01 1.63e-04 7.52e-04 -11.0 1.75e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
```

Compared to fmincon():

```
                                            First-order      Norm of
 Iter F-count            f(x)  Feasibility   optimality         step
    0       1    1.695878e-01    5.684e-14    1.102e-02
    1       2    1.691645e-01    1.296e-04    4.729e-03    2.229e-02
    2       3    1.665545e-01    7.175e-03    9.554e-03    1.857e-01
    3       4    1.635913e-01    4.118e-02    6.511e-03    5.518e-01
    4       5    1.626062e-01    3.235e-02    1.080e-02    6.491e-01
    5       6    1.617645e-01    2.861e-02    3.397e-03    7.418e-01
    6       7    1.607960e-01    1.297e-02    2.636e-03    6.037e-01
    7       8    1.595868e-01    4.010e-02    4.019e-03    1.089e+00
    8       9    1.589008e-01    2.304e-02    4.341e-03    7.246e-01
    9      10    1.581489e-01    3.965e-03    1.667e-03    2.636e-01
   10      11    1.575713e-01    1.046e-02    1.000e-03    6.139e-01
   11      12    1.573578e-01    3.968e-03    1.179e-03    4.697e-01
   12      13    1.570832e-01    4.880e-03    1.247e-03    6.278e-01
   13      14    1.567794e-01    5.258e-03    1.000e-03    6.424e-01
   14      15    1.567468e-01    7.916e-03    2.665e-03    6.705e-01
   15      16    1.565624e-01    1.995e-03    1.452e-03    1.778e-01
   16      17    1.565058e-01    9.510e-04    1.309e-03    1.582e-01
   17      18    1.564559e-01    8.874e-04    1.000e-03    2.408e-01
   18      19    1.556438e-01    2.632e-03    7.432e-04    2.010e-01
   19      21    1.542575e-01    1.763e-05    1.908e-03    6.447e-01
   20      23    1.538128e-01    8.862e-06    2.772e-03    3.140e-01
   21      24    1.535477e-01    1.020e-03    1.317e-03    1.241e-01
   22      25    1.531595e-01    2.294e-03    7.816e-04    2.747e-01
   23      26    1.529536e-01    5.902e-04    8.447e-04    1.609e-01
   24      28    1.524555e-01    4.137e-07    1.424e-03    4.367e-01
   25      30    1.521461e-01    2.148e-06    1.428e-03    2.705e-01
   26      31    1.520693e-01    3.572e-04    9.764e-04    7.670e-02
   27      33    1.518785e-01    1.542e-06    1.821e-03    3.113e-01
   28      34    1.516523e-01    7.795e-04    1.052e-03    1.813e-01
   29      35    1.515454e-01    3.468e-04    6.490e-04    1.431e-01
   30      36    1.514033e-01    6.813e-04    7.628e-04    2.445e-01

                                            First-order      Norm of
 Iter F-count            f(x)  Feasibility   optimality         step
   31      37    1.511966e-01    1.321e-03    1.065e-03    3.590e-01
   32      38    1.509549e-01    2.310e-03    9.453e-04    5.227e-01
   33      39    1.507060e-01    2.390e-03    1.893e-03    5.238e-01
   34      40    1.505274e-01    1.191e-03    4.680e-04    2.007e-01
   35      41    1.504018e-01    3.995e-04    7.486e-04    1.168e-01
   36      42    1.501441e-01    8.662e-04    5.371e-04    3.376e-01
   37      44    1.498647e-01    3.364e-06    1.694e-03    5.798e-01
   38      45    1.496842e-01    9.911e-04    7.416e-04    3.829e-01
   39      46    1.496415e-01    3.685e-04    5.740e-04    1.727e-01
   40      47    1.495934e-01    9.745e-04    1.368e-03    3.101e-01
   41      48    1.494941e-01    6.501e-04    6.743e-04    3.020e-01
   42      49    1.493509e-01    9.861e-04    3.953e-04    3.974e-01
   43      50    1.492265e-01    7.372e-04    6.141e-04    3.550e-01
   44      51    1.490722e-01    1.345e-03    7.354e-04    4.686e-01
   45      52    1.489949e-01    9.143e-04    5.345e-04    2.969e-01
   46      53    1.489130e-01    8.080e-04    7.258e-04    2.955e-01
   47      54    1.488745e-01    1.176e-03    1.445e-03    2.992e-01
   48      55    1.488323e-01    4.312e-04    5.706e-04    1.628e-01
   49      56    1.487758e-01    3.440e-04    8.374e-04    1.993e-01
   50      57    1.486999e-01    1.017e-03    6.874e-04    3.923e-01
   51      59    1.486946e-01    8.701e-06    3.005e-03    4.956e-01
   52      60    1.485959e-01    3.722e-04    9.674e-04    7.810e-02
   53      61    1.485395e-01    3.153e-04    5.199e-04    1.871e-01
   54      62    1.484944e-01    3.883e-04    9.311e-04    2.667e-01
   55      63    1.484078e-01    6.886e-04    1.208e-03    4.148e-01
   56      64    1.482546e-01    2.396e-03    1.258e-03    9.236e-01
   57      65    1.481228e-01    2.799e-03    1.541e-03    9.661e-01
   58      66    1.479890e-01    7.611e-04    5.626e-04    4.157e-01
   59      67    1.478692e-01    1.020e-03    9.555e-04    5.353e-01
   60      68    1.477201e-01    1.205e-03    2.336e-03    6.695e-01

                                            First-order      Norm of
 Iter F-count            f(x)  Feasibility   optimality         step
   61      69    1.474560e-01    3.556e-03    1.588e-03    1.439e+00
   62      70    1.471856e-01    2.773e-03    1.294e-03    1.377e+00
   63      71    1.469532e-01    1.536e-03    1.162e-03    8.180e-01
   64      72    1.467492e-01    1.390e-03    8.390e-04    7.719e-01
   65      73    1.464826e-01    2.369e-03    2.728e-03    1.328e+00
   66      74    1.461599e-01    2.225e-03    1.697e-03    1.276e+00
   67      75    1.458142e-01    2.839e-03    7.377e-04    1.729e+00
   68      76    1.455273e-01    1.941e-03    1.540e-03    1.555e+00
   69      77    1.451421e-01    2.727e-03    2.188e-03    2.072e+00
   70      78    1.446933e-01    6.136e-03    3.128e-03    2.527e+00
   71      79    1.442774e-01    4.200e-03    1.005e-03    1.977e+00
   72      80    1.440018e-01    1.392e-03    1.141e-03    4.495e-01
   73      81    1.436448e-01    3.002e-03    2.341e-03    1.335e+00
   74      82    1.432150e-01    4.996e-03    3.013e-03    1.999e+00
   75      83    1.427922e-01    3.273e-03    7.698e-04    1.622e+00
   76      84    1.424515e-01    1.755e-03    1.547e-03    1.999e+00
   77      85    1.420710e-01    1.985e-03    1.608e-03    2.162e+00
   78      86    1.414360e-01    5.327e-03    1.684e-03    3.757e+00
   79      88    1.410962e-01    8.909e-05    5.970e-03    7.093e+00
   80      89    1.405116e-01    3.316e-03    1.177e-03    8.055e-01
   81      90    1.402913e-01    1.138e-03    1.549e-03    3.040e-01
   82      91    1.398874e-01    3.111e-03    2.327e-03    1.897e+00
   83      93    1.391672e-01    3.531e-06    3.701e-03    5.891e+00
   84      95    1.383758e-01    5.642e-05    3.542e-03    6.218e+00
   85      96    1.378290e-01    4.166e-03    1.036e-03    2.995e+00
   86      97    1.375162e-01    1.780e-03    1.041e-03    1.597e+00
   87      98    1.370376e-01    5.208e-03    1.925e-03    3.465e+00
   88      99    1.366982e-01    7.099e-03    4.238e-03    3.143e+00
   89     100    1.362886e-01    2.651e-03    2.194e-03    2.074e+00
   90     101    1.360006e-01    2.295e-03    1.189e-03    1.023e+00

                                            First-order      Norm of
 Iter F-count            f(x)  Feasibility   optimality         step
   91     102    1.358196e-01    9.869e-04    1.742e-03    1.240e+00
   92     103    1.355212e-01    2.761e-03    1.672e-03    1.891e+00
   93     105    1.353705e-01    1.162e-04    4.479e-03    4.375e+00
   94     106    1.348992e-01    2.477e-03    1.632e-03    3.747e-01
   95     107    1.347110e-01    1.267e-03    1.224e-03    3.268e-01
   96     108    1.345712e-01    8.739e-04    1.756e-03    8.004e-01
   97     109    1.343092e-01    3.165e-03    2.251e-03    1.691e+00
   98     111    1.341921e-01    4.984e-03    2.419e-03    1.037e+00
   99     112    1.339379e-01    1.967e-03    9.087e-04    2.052e+00
```

I don't really have any experience with either the theory or practice of optimization, so I'm wondering if anyone can help spot the issue here? Is there any way I can tweak the options I'm passing to IPOPT to solve the problem or is IPOPT simply less suited to this type of optimization problem?

For reference, here's the python code:

```py
class initial_problem():
    def __init__(self, cell_pairs, dC):
        self.cell_pairs = cell_pairs
        self.dC = dC

    def objective(self, x):
        x = x.reshape(x0.shape, order='F')
        q = x[:,0:2]
        p = x[:,2]

        b = np.matmul(self.dC, np.multiply(q.T,p).T)
        delta_p = np.matmul(self.dC, p)

        t1 = np.divide((b - (np.multiply(r1.T,delta_p).T)).T,np.linalg.norm(b - (np.multiply(r1.T,delta_p).T), axis=1)).T
        t2 = np.divide((b - (np.multiply(r2.T,delta_p).T)).T,np.linalg.norm(b - (np.multiply(r2.T,delta_p).T), axis=1)).T

        E = 0.5 * np.mean(np.power(np.sum(t1 * tau_1, axis=1), 2) +
                          np.power(np.sum(t2 * tau_2, axis=1), 2))
        return E

    def gradient(self, x):
        # Jacobian of objective
        x = x.reshape(x0.shape, order='F')
        q = x[:,0:2]
        p = x[:,2]

        b = np.matmul(self.dC, np.multiply(q.T,p).T)
        delta_p = np.matmul(self.dC, p)

        t1 = np.divide((b - (np.multiply(r1.T,delta_p).T)).T,np.linalg.norm(b - (np.multiply(r1.T,delta_p).T), axis=1)).T
        t2 = np.divide((b - (np.multiply(r2.T,delta_p).T)).T,np.linalg.norm(b - (np.multiply(r2.T,delta_p).T), axis=1)).T

        ip1 = np.sum(t1 * tau_1, axis=1)
        ip2 = np.sum(t2 * tau_2, axis=1)

        drX1 = sx_grad(p[self.cell_pairs[:,0]], p[self.cell_pairs[:,1]], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],1], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],1], r1[:,0], r1[:,1])
        drX2 = sx_grad(p[self.cell_pairs[:,0]], p[self.cell_pairs[:,1]], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],1], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],1], r2[:,0], r2[:,1])
        drY1 = sy_grad(p[self.cell_pairs[:,0]], p[self.cell_pairs[:,1]], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],1], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],1], r1[:,0], r1[:,1])
        drY2 = sy_grad(p[self.cell_pairs[:,0]], p[self.cell_pairs[:,1]], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],1], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],1], r2[:,0], r2[:,1])

        dE = np.multiply(ip1 * tau_1[:,0], drX1.T).T + np.multiply(ip1 * tau_1[:,1], drY1.T).T + \
             np.multiply(ip2 * tau_2[:,0], drX2.T).T + np.multiply(ip2 * tau_2[:,1], drY2.T).T
        dE = dE / self.dC.shape[0]

        rows = np.concatenate([self.cell_pairs[:,0],self.cell_pairs[:,0]+self.dC.shape[1],self.cell_pairs[:,0]+2*self.dC.shape[1],
                               self.cell_pairs[:,1],self.cell_pairs[:,1]+self.dC.shape[1],self.cell_pairs[:,1]+2*self.dC.shape[1]])

        dE = np.bincount(rows, weights=np.ravel(dE,order='F'))
        return dE

    # Define constraints
    def constraints(self, x):
        # linear constraint
        Aeq = np.concatenate((np.zeros(x0.shape[0]*2), np.ones(x0.shape[0])))
        lincon = np.dot(Aeq, x)

        # nonlinear constraint
        x = x.reshape(x0.shape, order='F')
        q = x[:,0:2]
        p = x[:,2]

        b = np.matmul(self.dC, np.multiply(q.T,p).T)
        delta_p = np.matmul(self.dC, p)

        l1 = np.linalg.norm(b - (np.multiply(r1.T,delta_p).T), axis=1)
        l2 = np.linalg.norm(b - (np.multiply(r2.T,delta_p).T), axis=1)

        nonlincon = 0.5*(np.mean(l1) + np.mean(l2)) - scale

        cons = np.append(nonlincon, lincon)
        return cons

    def jacobian(self, x):
        # Jacobian of nonlinear constraints
        x = x.reshape(x0.shape, order='F')
        q = x[:,0:2]
        p = x[:,2]

        b = np.matmul(self.dC, np.multiply(q.T,p).T)
        delta_p = np.matmul(self.dC, p)

        t1 = np.divide((b - (np.multiply(r1.T,delta_p).T)).T,np.linalg.norm(b - (np.multiply(r1.T,delta_p).T), axis=1)).T
        t2 = np.divide((b - (np.multiply(r2.T,delta_p).T)).T,np.linalg.norm(b - (np.multiply(r2.T,delta_p).T), axis=1)).T

        drX1 = rx_grad(p[self.cell_pairs[:,0]], p[self.cell_pairs[:,1]], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],0], r1[:,0])
        drX2 = rx_grad(p[self.cell_pairs[:,0]], p[self.cell_pairs[:,1]], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],0], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],0], r2[:,0])
        drY1 = ry_grad(p[self.cell_pairs[:,0]], p[self.cell_pairs[:,1]], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],1], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],1], r1[:,1])
        drY2 = ry_grad(p[self.cell_pairs[:,0]], p[self.cell_pairs[:,1]], q[self.cell_pairs[:,0],1], q[self.cell_pairs[:,1],1], r2[:,1])


        dE = 0.5 * (np.multiply(t1[:,0],drX1.T).T + np.multiply(t1[:,1],drY1.T).T) + \
             0.5 * (np.multiply(t2[:,0],drX2.T).T + np.multiply(t2[:,1],drY2.T).T)

        rows = np.concatenate([self.cell_pairs[:,0],self.cell_pairs[:,0]+self.dC.shape[1],self.cell_pairs[:,0]+2*self.dC.shape[1],
                               self.cell_pairs[:,1],self.cell_pairs[:,1]+self.dC.shape[1],self.cell_pairs[:,1]+2*self.dC.shape[1]])

        dE = np.bincount(rows, weights=np.ravel(dE/self.dC.shape[0],order='F'))

        # Add jacobian of linear constraints
        lin_dE = np.concatenate((np.zeros(2*x0.shape[0]), np.ones(x0.shape[0])))

        jac = np.concatenate([dE, lin_dE])
        return jac

initial_minimization = cyipopt.Problem(
    n = x0.size,
    m = 2,
    problem_obj = initial_problem(self.cell_pairs,self.dC),
    lb = np.concatenate((-np.inf*np.ones(x0.shape[0]), -np.inf*np.ones(x0.shape[0]), 0.001*np.ones(x0.shape[0]))),
    ub = np.concatenate((np.inf*np.ones(x0.shape[0]), np.inf*np.ones(x0.shape[0]), 1000*np.ones(x0.shape[0]))),
    cl = np.array([0, np.mean(p0)*p0.shape[0]]),
    cu = np.array([0, np.mean(p0)*p0.shape[0]])
)

initial_minimization.add_option('max_iter',2000)
initial_minimization.add_option('tol',1e-5)
initial_minimization.add_option('nlp_scaling_method','none')
initial_minimization.add_option('print_timing_statistics','yes')
initial_minimization.add_option('hessian_approximation','limited-memory')

res = initial_minimization.solve(x0.ravel(order='F'))
```

Compared to the original matlab code:

```matlab
energyFunc = @(x) reducedEnergy( x, sparse(d0), t1, t2, r1, r2, bCells );
nonlinFunc = @(x) mycon( x, sparse(d0), Lscale, r1, r2, bCells );

lb = -inf*ones(size(x0));
lb(:,3) = .001;
ub = inf*ones(size(x0));
ub(:,3) = 1000;

Aeq = [zeros(1,size(d0,2)),zeros(1,size(d0,2)),ones(1,size(d0,2))];
beq = size(d0,2)*mean(p);

optimset = optimoptions('fmincon','Display','iter-detailed','Algorithm','interior-point','MaxFunEvals',2e6,...
                        'MaxIter',2e3,'TolFun',1e-5,'GradObj','on','GradConstr','on',...
                        'HessianApproximation','lbfgs');
                    
[x,ERes] = fmincon(energyFunc,x0,[],[],Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlinFunc,optimset);


function [ clin, ceq, dlin, deq ] = mycon( x, d0, Lscale, r1, r2, bCells )

    NB = size(d0,1);
    NC = size(d0,2);
    q = x(:,1:2);
    p = x(:,3);
    clin = [];
    
    B = d0*bsxfun(@times,q,p);
    deltaP = d0*p;

    B1 = B - bsxfun(@times,deltaP,r1);
    B2 = B - bsxfun(@times,deltaP,r2);

    L1 = sqrt(sum(B1.^2,2));
    B1 = bsxfun(@rdivide,B1,L1);
    
    L2 = sqrt(sum(B2.^2,2));
    B2 = bsxfun(@rdivide,B2,L2);
    
    ceq = .5*(mean(L1) + mean(L2)) - Lscale;
    if (nargout > 2)
        dlin = [];
        deq = .5*(bsxfun(@times,B1(:,1),drX1) + bsxfun(@times,B1(:,2),drY1)) + ...
              .5*(bsxfun(@times,B2(:,1),drX2) + bsxfun(@times,B2(:,2),drY2));
        rows = [bCells(:,1);bCells(:,1)+NC;bCells(:,1)+2*NC;bCells(:,2);bCells(:,2)+NC;bCells(:,2)+2*NC];
        deq = accumarray(rows,deq(:)/NB,[3*NC,1]);
    end
end


function [ E, dE ] = reducedEnergy( x, d0, t1, t2, r1, r2, bCells )
    
    q = x(:,1:2);
    p = x(:,3);

    B = d0*bsxfun(@times,q,p);
    deltaP = d0*p;

    B1 = B - bsxfun(@times,deltaP,r1);
    B2 = B - bsxfun(@times,deltaP,r2);

    L1 = sqrt(sum(B1.^2,2));
    B1 = bsxfun(@rdivide,B1,L1);
    L2 = sqrt(sum(B2.^2,2));
    B2 = bsxfun(@rdivide,B2,L2);

    E = .5*mean( dot(B1,t1,2).^2 + dot(B2,t2,2).^2 );

    if (nargout == 2)
        NB = size(d0,1);
        NC = size(d0,2);
        [ drX1, drY1, drX2, drY2 ] = fitDual.AFN.reducedLocalGrads( q, p, bCells, r1 ,r2 );

        IP1 = dot(B1,t1,2);
        IP2 = dot(B2,t2,2);

        dE = bsxfun(@times,IP1.*t1(:,1),drX1) + bsxfun(@times,IP1.*t1(:,2),drY1) + ...
             bsxfun(@times,IP2.*t2(:,1),drX2) + bsxfun(@times,IP2.*t2(:,2),drY2);
        dE = dE / NB;
        rows = [bCells(:,1);bCells(:,1)+NC;bCells(:,1)+2*NC;bCells(:,2);bCells(:,2)+NC;bCells(:,2)+2*NC];
        vals = dE(:);
        dE = accumarray(rows,vals',[3*NC,1]);

    end
end
```

Comment: Can you please provide **reproducible** code snippets? Otherwise, it's hard to help properly. Both, the Matlab and the python code are missing several variables, i.e. what are `x0, cell_pairs, dC,d0, t1, t2, r1, r2, bCells` etc?

Comment: Each of these variables are large arrays (~800x2 or 800x1) so I'm not sure how to include these in a logical manner, especially since some of these differ between the matlab and python code (as matlab is 1-indexed).